# How to get a map object, from a list object which contains multiple different mysql dates using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How to get a map object which contains Key as a string and Value as a List object, from a list object which contains multiple different MySQL dates using java 8 stream.

Example:

```
List listObj = new ArrayList<>(); 
listObj.add("2018-04-21"); 
listObj.add("2018-05-20"); 
listObj.add("2018-04-22"); 
listObj.add("2018-03-29"); 
listObj.add("2018-03-10");
```

expected Map object should be like:

if I am printing the map object output:

```
[March, "2018-03-29","2018-03-10"] [April, "2018-04-21","2018-04-22"] [May, "2018-05-20"]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? show us your work

Comment: There are no “multiple different MySQL dates” in your example. There are just `String`s in a particular, very common date format.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse to date and group by month:

```
List<String> listObj = new ArrayList<>(); //use String type argument
// ... add elements

Map<Month, List<LocalDate>> map = listObj.stream()
        .map(LocalDate::parse)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth));
```

Printing `map` outputs:

```
{MAY=[2018-05-20], MARCH=[2018-03-29, 2018-03-10], APRIL=[2018-04-21, 2018-04-22]}
```

If you rather need a `Map<String, List<String>>`, then you can change the last line to

```
...collect(Collectors.groupingBy(date -> date.getMonth().toString(), 
        Collectors.mapping(LocalDate::toString, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Map<String, List<String>> map = listObj
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> LocalDate.parse(v).getMonth().name()));
```

Answer (score 0):

for (String date : listObj ) { java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date); String keyMonth = Month.of(sqlDate.getMonth() + 1).name(); if (mapObj.containsKey(keyMonth)) { mapObj.get(keyMonth).add(sqlDate); } else { List list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(sqlDate); mapObj.put(keyMonth, list); } }